# how to make a command only work in a specific channel using discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

currently i am using

```py
vouch_channel = client.get_channel(828696942250295316)

@client.command()
async def vouch(message):
  async def vouch(ctx,member : discord.Member):

    if ctx.author == member:
        await ctx.send("You can't vouch yourself")

       
      if message.channel.id == vouch_channel.id:


        auth = ctx.author and ctx.author.mention and ctx.author.id
        await open_vouches(ctx.author)
        await open_vouches(member)



        await update_vouches(member,+1,'vouches_gotten')
        await update_vouches(ctx.author,+1,'vouches_given')      
        await ctx.reply(f'<:icon_checkmark:827639277285408829> {ctx.author.mention} You vouched for {member}!')
       print('[LOGS] bot was used for vouch')



      else:
            #command attempted in non command channel - redirect user
            await message.channel.send('Write this command in {}'.format(vouch_channel.mention))
```

to try and do this and i have tried changing the things around but it didnt work.

could i please have some help as i really dont know what to do

i also triad doing

```
@client.command()
async def vouch(message,ctx,member : discord.member):
```

instead of doing what i did there and i also tried

```
@client.command()
async def vouch(message)(ctx,member : discord.member):
```

but that didn't work either.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it seems that your parameter order is off in your functions. If you're not using a cog, ctx should be the first parameter to be passed.
You might also have issues with multi-word messages, so you can use the * argument to say "Everything after the second argument passed is part of message".

Try out the below code. You'd be able to use the command as follows: `!vouch @Kelo This is my message`

```
@client.command()
async def vouch(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, message):
  if ctx.author == member:
    await ctx.send("You can't vouch yourself")
    return
  elif ctx.channel.id != 828696942250295316:
    await ctx.send("You can't vouch in this channel")
    return
  
  #Rest of your code
```

Comment: is the `!` for the prefix?


also to add the rest of the code would i do
```
other:
```

Comment: how would i make it so i can have 2 channels?

Comment: yeah it's for the prefix. And you can use the and operator in if conditions.

Comment: hey could you please help me with my other question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66970008/15564722 as i really don't know what to do as this only works for this command not that one

Comment: If you want to have it for 2 channels, you could easily make a list of channels where vouching is supported. Then, you check, if the ctx.channel.id is not in the list, you can't vouch; otherwise you are vouched.