# how do i make this command only work in multiple channels using discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

i am trying to make a command work in 2 trade channels as it is for checking peoples vouches to see if they are trustworthy. my current code doesn't work but here it is

```
@client.command()
async def vouches(ctx, member : discord.User=None):
  if None == member:
  
    await open_vouches(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_vouch_data()

    vouches_given = users[str(user.id)]["vouches_given"]
    vouches_gotten = users[str(user.id)]["vouches_gotten"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title='Trade vouches!',color=0x1d9521)
    embed.add_field(name='Vouches Gotten✨',value=vouches_gotten, inline=False)    
    embed.add_field(name="Vouches Given", value=vouches_given, inline=False)

    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
  

  elif ctx.channel.id != 813832766248583199:
    await ctx.send("You can't vouch in this channel")
    return
  elif ctx.channel.id != 813832801220689931:
    await ctx.send("You can't vouch in this channel")
    return
    
  
  else:
    await open_vouches(member)

    users = await get_vouch_data()

    vouches_given = users[str(member.id)]["vouches_given"]
    vouches_gotten = users[str(member.id)]["vouches_gotten"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{member}\'s Trade vouches!',color=0x1d9521)
    embed.add_field(name='Vouches Gotten✨',value=vouches_gotten, inline=False)    
    embed.add_field(name="Vouches Given", value=vouches_given, inline=False)

    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    print('[LOGS] bot was used for Vouches')
```

but the elif: part is what i am trying to use. I asked a similar question to this earlier but only using one channel so please help me. thankyou in advance and yes i have tried putting the id's in together and things like that

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Saying "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful for us to help you out here. Any errors? Any strange behaviour? Tried debug printing to see what parts of the code you reach & which you don't?

Comment: well it doesn't even try work as in it is just ignored and the command goes on anyways

Comment: How are you using the command?

Comment: i am doing =vouches and it tells a person how many vouches they have and how many vouches they have given

Comment: If you're doing that, then `member` is always `None` because you're not passing one, and it will get into your first `if`, not the ones below where the channel id is checked.

Comment: but people also need to see other peoples vouches

Comment: Then pass a member instead of leaving it blank. `=vouches @member`

Comment: oh thnx i forgot i would have to do that. would i have to put `elif:` on top of the first command?

Comment: I'll just add it as an answer, I have enough info now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you have to **first** check the channels. In the comments you mentioned you don't pass a member as an argument when testing, meaning that that part of the code is never reached as `member` is always `None` so it gets into the first `if`.

```py
@client.command()
async def vouches(ctx, member : discord.User=None):
    allowed_channels = [813832766248583199, 813832801220689931]

    # Check channels FIRST
    if ctx.channel.id not in allowed_channels:
        return await ctx.send("You can't vouch in this channel")
```

Also, `None-checks` should be done using `is`, not `==`.

```py
    elif member is None:
        ...
```

PS. This isn't *wrong*, but using `elif` is unnecessary if the `if-statements` above use `return`s. In case one of the above `if/elif`'s was entered, the function `return`s, so there's no way to reach the `elif`'s below anyways.

Lastly, the code for `member is None` and `members is not None` is the exact same using a different `userid`, consider just creating a variable with the `id` or creating a function instead of duplicating that block of code.